# MAUI iOS build won't build even for a debug build

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, sqlite, maui

We recently upgraded our mac at the company so we could update to xcode 15 (we were previously stuck to xcode 14.2). When I went to build the app we are developing for quite some time now for iOS I encountered a problem with clang++, to be exact it threw this error

```
clang exited with code1:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lSystem.IO.Compression.Native', '-lSystem.Native', '-lSystem.Net.Security.Native', '-lSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple', '-lcompression', '-lmono-component-debugger', '-lmono-component-diagnostics_tracing', '-lmono-component-hot_reload', '-lmonosgen-2.0', '-lxamarin-dotnet-debug'
ld: building for 'iOS-simulator', but linking in object file (/Users/user/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Project/8618b5190f6d6128dea985b3e984c867243d6f87f73c5927fc8c844f1e1e1b50/obj/Debug/net7.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/e_sqlite3.a[arm64][2](sqlite3.o)) built for 'iOS'
1>clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After looking at the project I found the cause of the issue. The application uses a library by Dev Express for XPO, this library relies on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite and this library specifically, when installed, produces the issue.

I tried different version of said library, specifically I tried the following

1. 7.0.0
2. 7.0.1
3. 7.0.2
4. 7.0.3
5. 7.0.4
6. 7.0.5
7. 7.0.7
8. 7.0.8
9. 7.0.9
10. 7.0.10
11. 7.0.11

Still no dice, I even created a whole new project and individually added the libraries one by one and it still crashes on the new application once Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is installed.

As a desperate measure I even changed the simulator from 17.0 to 16.2 and you can guess how well that went.

Comment: Have you tried using sqlite-net-pcl as in [.NET MAUI local databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite)

Comment: Just tried that with and withoutMicrosoft.Data.Sqlite, just for good measure. Without it I could get it to build the application but when it tried to run it after a while it threw an error, that error being System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not find assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite'.'. DevExpress.XPO in my knowledge requires Microsoft.Data.Sqlite so it is impossible to not use it without the library they have over at microsoft.

Comment: So sick of .net maui.  How is it that I come back to my project a week later and the same code that was building now just won't build for error like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with Dev Express support and got my answer. The problem seems to be on the Microsoft side of things, it is weird that it didn't work on iOS 16.2 but I haven't tested multiple versions of Microsoft.Data.Sqlite on iOS 16.2 and 16.1.

This might be resolved in the future when Microsoft.Data.Sqlite 8.0.0 comes out, right now it is at a pre-release state.

If I hear anything else from Dev Express I will just add a comment to this post to inform you.

Comment: They told me to use System.Data.SQLite instead, specifically version 1.0.116. This did not resolve my issue per se but it might solve the issue of someone else in the future. If it doesn't then you have to wait for Microsoft to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" and "sqlite-net-pcl" are installed in Xamarin / Maui, and deleting one of them can run perfectly.
Sqlite-net-pcl used by official documents.
But I think EFcore.sqlite is stronger.